# Get indices of string occurrences in cell-array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array that contains a long list of strings. Most of the strings are in duplicates. I need the indices of instances of a string within the cell array.

I tried the following:

`[bool,ind] = ismember(string,var);`

Which consistently returns scalar `ind` while there are clearly more than one index for which the contents in the cell array matches `string`.

How can I have a list of indices that points to the locations in the cell array that contains `string`?

Comment: Is `var` the cell array? Then, use `ismember(var,string)`.

Comment: Ok, then passing it through `find` does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Divakar's comment, you could use [`strcmp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html). This works even if some cell doesn't contain a string:

```
>> strcmp('aaa', {'aaa', 'bb', 'aaa', 'c', 25, [1 2 3]})
ans =
     1     0     1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can ID each string and thus have representative numeric arrays corresponding to the input cell array and string. For *ID*ing, you can use [`unique`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and then use `find` as you would with numeric arrays. Here's how you can achieve that -

```
var_ext = [var string]
[~,~,idx] = unique(var_ext)
out = find(idx(1:end-1)==idx(end))
```

**Breakdown of the code:**

- `var_ext = [var string]`: Concatenate everything (string and var) into a single cell array, with the string ending up at the end (last element) of it.
- `[~,~,idx] = unique(var_ext)`: ID everything in that concatenated cell array.
- `find(idx(1:end-1)==idx(end))`: `idx(1:end-1)` represents the numeric IDs for the cell array elements and `idx(end)` would be the ID for the `string`. Compare these IDs and use `find` to pick up the matching indices to give us the final output.

---

Sample run -

Inputs:

```
var = {'er','meh','nop','meh','ya','meh'}
string = 'meh'
```

Output:

```
out =
     2
     4
     6
```

Answer (score -1):

regexp would solve this problem better and the easy way.

```
string  = ['my' 'bat' 'my' 'ball' 'my' 'score']
expression = ['my']

regexp(string,expresssion)
ans = 1 6 12
```